# Ubuntu phone - How can I delete the contacts in my phone book properly?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, sync, delete, contacts, bq

I am importing my contacts into my personal address book in the following way:

syncevolution --import /path/to/file/allcontacts.vcf backend=evolution-contacts

To keep them updated I delete all the contacts in my address book and do the same procedure with the new .vcf-file. This worked fine till some weeks ago. Now the contacts get still normally listed in my address book BUT if I search a contact this contact is shown more times. The number of the same contact that I see correspond to the number of executions of this:

syncevolution --import /path/to/file/allcontacts.vcf backend=evolution-contacts

So I think that I do not delete my old contacts properly before I import them again. But how can I delete my contacts properly in my phone book?

Comment: You can use **syncevolution** following this ==> http://askubuntu.com/questions/720446/how-to-purge-all-contacts .

Answer (score 3):

To delete the local contacts in a proper way go to /home/phablet/.local/share/evolution/addressbook/system and delete the contacts.db file.
Maybe you need to restart your Ubuntu phone.