# How to purge all contacts

Tags: command-line, sync, contacts, purge

How can I purge all my contacts on my bq E5 Ubuntu Edition?
I am am just trying to fill my new E5 with the thousands of contacts I have on my old Communicator. Soon I will get repeated contacts, or corrupted ones. 
A purge command would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use this comand line on a Terminal window/app:

> syncevolution --delete-items backend=evolution-contacts --luids '*'

I found this on=> https://gurucubano.gitbooks.io/bq-aquaris-e-4-5-ubuntu-phone/content/en/index.html, a collection of knowhow on Ubuntu Touch (search for the index item "Import and export of Contacts").

There seems to exist several similar questions, but I have not found another satisfactory answer, excepting a way by deleting the contact database, ==>[Ubuntu phone - How can I delete the contacts in my phone book properly?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/709852/ubuntu-phone-how-can-i-delete-the-contacts-in-my-phone-book-properly#autocomment1064864).

Comment: Also: In Evolution, go to Contatcs, select all contacts by clicking the first and shift clicking the last, delete.